# Response of Jquery Ajax dont appear Screen, some in Firebug console

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I making a requisition in ajax whit rails and the result of response is correct, the console of Firebug appear this:

```
$("#cost_select").after("<select id="from_money" name="from_money"><option value="2">Luz</option></select>
");
```

The problem is this dont appear, i try change the tag html and works fine, i dont know what is dont appear the select in screen someone can help ? i need appear this normal all is correct the variables and all i make the dynamic content in Rails.

Comment: can you include your `.js.erb` file in your question?

Comment: the fragment of code when input is the my .js.erb

Comment: if that is your `.js.erb` file, then there's an error with the string.  try `$("#cost_select").after("<select id='from_money' name='from_money'><option value='2'>Luz</option></select>
");`

Comment: Undertand, but im using this code in rails to generate the html: `$("#cost_select").after("<%= select_tag 'from_money', options_for_select(@places.map { |c| ["#{c.place}", c.id] }) %>
");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the javascript so quotes will be escaped.

```
$("#cost_select").after("<%= escape_javascript select_tag('from_money', options_for_select(@places.map { |c| [c.place, c.id] })) %> ");
```

Comment: No works, dont appear, some change the response to this in Firebug response: `$("#cost_select").after("<select id=\"from_money\" name=\"from_money\"><option value=\"1\">Sicredi<\/option>\n<option value=\"3\">Banco do Brasil<\/option>\n<option value=\"4\">Sicredi<\/option><\/select>
");`i put the select in partial and works

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that last line.  if you say it's working already then good for you.

Comment: Thanks, but my mode is primitive hehe, i dont understand because you response dont works, the html generate is escaped i see but dont appear, i really prefer 1000 times your way, that's right.